# Creating a stretched semi circle

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a uiview where the top has a stretched semi circle cropped out. I've figured out below to crop a semi circle, however i can not seem to figure out how to make it smaller like below image.

Here you see a grey image where a smaller semi circle is cropped out:

[image]

Code so far:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: bounds.origin)
    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: bounds.origin.y)
    path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: bounds.size.width / 2.0, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, y: bounds.origin.y))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width, y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height))
    path.close()

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath

    layer.mask = mask
```

Comment: You are on the right path. Try curves instead of arc and lines.

Comment: Here is the reference. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624357-addcurve You need two curves to achieve what you need.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624357-addcurve. Also recommend you look at bounds.midX, bounds.maxX and their Y equivalents. bounds.origin.x will usually be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
func addParabolaWithMax()  {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    let p0 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let p2 = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: 100)

    let p1 = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    path.move(to: p1)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: p0, controlPoint: p2)

    path.lineWidth = 1
    path.stroke()
    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    line.path = path.cgPath;
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    line.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(line)
}
```

[image]

Comment: seem to work great. is there anyway to make so that the blue color is the color of the background view? so that it is transparent.

Comment: give color with alpha

Comment: To reverse this, you need to add in extra `path.addLine`s to the bottom left and right.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        setMask(control: CGPoint(x: 40.0, y: 100.0))
    }

    func setMask(control: CGPoint) {
        let bounds = view.bounds
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: bounds.origin)
        let control2 = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - control.x, y: control.y)
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY), controlPoint1: control, controlPoint2: control2)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.close()
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        view.layer.mask = mask

    }
}
```

By adjusting the control point you can change the curvature (simulator screenshot from iPhone X hence the rounded top corners!).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I can only seem to post a single image to an answer, here's how the control points work in bezier curves and how by adjusting the control points you can change the arc of the curve:

[image]

`C2` is simply `bounds.max - C1.x, C1.y`.